# Problem with balance of my address

Tags: transactions, wallet, address

I have a problem that wallet does not recognize transactions of my address. The problem is present on testnet.

Relevant address is n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj (https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/address/n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj).

```
bitcoin-cli validateaddress n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj",
  ...
  "ismine": true,
  ...
}
```

Transaction 405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850 (https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850) is having my address as an output:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850 1
{
  "txid": "405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850",
  ...
  "vin": [
  ...
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.49953560,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        ...
        "addresses": [
          "mxiFoE5bNxXMRdgXyFrc6zW3aw7zsuynSK"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 16.05588800,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        ...
        "addresses": [
          "n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

But my node does not recognize it:

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 0 9999999 "[\"n3qPR7uHUSoqnd8DZpE8GVhqnmrMzYu7Vj\"]"
[
]

bitcoin-cli gettransaction 405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850
{
  "amount": 0.00000000,
  ...
  "txid": "405920020c236f3faa483b72baf5181955ac25f8946323f9f0827b94e08a2850",
  ...
  "details": [
    {
      "account": "",
      "address": "mxiFoE5bNxXMRdgXyFrc6zW3aw7zsuynSK",
      "category": "send",
      "amount": -0.49953560,
      "fee": -0.00046440,
      "abandoned": false
      ...
    }, 
    {
      "account": "",
      "address": "mxiFoE5bNxXMRdgXyFrc6zW3aw7zsuynSK",
      "category": "receive",
      "amount": 0.49953560,
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Rescan of the node didn't help.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if I export (dumpprivkey) the private key (from this problematic address) from my wallet and import to some other wallet (node) then the balance for this address is correct and I can spend that amount.

Comment: The transaction I mentioned is from my address to my address and therefore `gettransaction` returned amount = 0.
It seems that my node recognize spending but not receiving of BTCs by that transactoin.

Comment: Copying a wallet.dat file from one node to the other didn't help.